# How to use apache axis 2 to create a dummy web service?

Tags: apache-axis

I have a WSDL from a C# web service.
Can anyone advice on how to use apache axis 2 to create a dummy web service?

Answer (score 0):

Use Axis2's wsdl2java.  It will generate a runnable skeleton.  Just take out the exceptions and make each operation return a canned response.